# HashMap counting values

Tags: java

So below I have tried to demonstrate a somewhat realistic version for how my program is implemented using pseudo code.. so I have a hashmap . I intended on reading a text and incrementing whenever a character of the alphabet is added; so the end result would be if e.g. "doog" d=1 o=2 g=1.

It does loop through the text and return the values however it's giving me an incorrect calculation for each character. My code seems perfectly valid and it is calculating the characters, but just not equating to what it should be =/ if anyone has any thoughts on why this is being calculated wrong then please explain to me.

```
while((text = something.readLine()) != null){

        for i = 0; i < text i++
        {
            if (hash map already contains the key at text.charAt(i){
                continue;
            }add the following to my hashmap(text.charAt(i), incrementer++); 
            }
            else{
            add (text.charAt(i), incrementer);  
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share the actual code?

Comment: If it already contains the key, you need to increment the count and not do a ```continue;```

Comment: There are problems where pseudocode could help visibility, present an idea uncluttered by useless details. This is not the case, full code would be barely longer (like `hash map already contains the key`) and debugging it would be of more use to you.

Comment: Probaly it is a homework, and therefore he should not post.

Comment: Your pseudo code has not a correct syntax:  Around "add the following" there is  a missing else

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to read your Pseudo code, but I think you are incrementing too many times within loop. Which is probably making it miss a character or two for every evaluation of the presence in hash map. Just increment in the for loop definition and it should work well.

Answer (score 0):

One bug:
The continue statement: In java it will jump to the for loop, and will not incerement the character counter in the hashmap, but it should do.

Answer (score 0):

The subject line should have been more clear if your intention is to count the occurrences of characters in a String.

```
public static Map<String, Integer> getOccurences(String string) {
    Map<String, Integer> occurenceMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    String[] strArray = string.split(StringUtils.EMPTY);
    int count = 0;
    for(String str : strArray) {
        if(occurenceMap.containsKey(str)) {
            continue;
        }
        count = StringUtils.countMatches(string, str);
        occurenceMap.put(str, count);

    }
    return occurenceMap;
}
```

Alternate version without Apache Commons.

```
public static Map<String, Integer> getOccurences(String string) {
    Map<String, Integer> occurenceMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    String[] strArray = string.split("");
    int count = 0;
    for(String str : strArray) {
        if(occurenceMap.containsKey(str)) {
            count = occurenceMap.get(str).intValue();
            count++;
        } else {
            count = 1;
        }
        occurenceMap.put(str, count);

    }
    return occurenceMap;
}
```